# Why trust vaccine statistics from the mid-20th century, if ELISA tests were not available and disease diagnoses were completely subjective?

Tags: human-biology

Why trust vaccine statistics from the mid-20th century, if ELISA tests were not available and disease diagnoses were completely subjective? Any answer is helpful. Please let me know.

Comment: Diagnoses were not completely subjective; there are myriad assays besides ELISA.

Comment: what do you mean by "vaccine statistics" exactly? To me that would denote information about the number of people vaccinated, which would be standard bureaucratic record-keeping. Do you mean statistics on the incidence and/or prevalence of infectious diseases? Or estimates of vaccine efficacy/disease prevention (which would boil down to a comparison of the previous two sets of data)?

Comment: Can you please add some more details to your question? Don't simply copy paste the title in the body. Add references, your own research etc to provide background to your question.

Answer (score 1):

> Diagnoses were not completely subjective; there are myriad assays besides ELISA.

Not back then.

https://emedicine.medscape.com/article/966220-workup

Although the diagnosis of measles is usually determined from the classic clinical picture (see Clinical), laboratory identification and confirmation of the diagnosis are necessary for the purposes of public health and outbreak control. Laboratory confirmation is achieved by means of serologic testing for immunoglobulin G (IgG) and M (IgM) antibodies, isolation of the virus, and reverse-transcriptase polymerase chain reaction (RT-PCR) evaluation.

None of this existed in 1970.

Comment: What about Pasteur though? He determined the first vaccine via observation of resistance to symptoms. Don't his observations count as somewhat objective? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Louis_Pasteur#Immunology_and_vaccination

Comment: For measles in particular, [Koplik's spots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Koplik%27s_spots), described in 1896, are a fairly reliable diagnostic indicator.

Comment: The fact that we have better, more definitive, assays now does not imply that previous assays or clinical observations were purely subjective.